# how do I insert data when the DB value of "position" is equal to "id" in jquery-file-upload

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, jquery-file-upload

how do I insert data when the DB value of "position" is equal to "id",  in jquery-file-upload, thanks

```
if (empty($file->error)) {
            $sql = 'INSERT INTO `'.$this->options['db_table']
                .'` (`name`, `size`, `type`, `title`, `description`, `position`)'
                .' VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)';
            $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
            $query->bind_param(
                'sisssi',
                $file->name,
                $file->size,
                $file->type,
                $file->title,
                $file->description,
                $file->position
            );
            $query->execute();
            $file->id = $this->db->insert_id;
        }
        return $file;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do it in 2 steps:

```
if (empty($file->error)) {
        $sql = 'INSERT INTO `'.$this->options['db_table']
            .'` (`name`, `size`, `type`, `title`, `description`)'
            .' VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)';
        $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $query->bind_param(
            $file->name,
            $file->size,
            $file->type,
            $file->title,
            $file->description
        );
        $query->execute();
        $file->id = $this->db->insert_id;

        $sql = 'UPDATE `'.$this->options['db_table']
            .'` SET `position` = `id` WHERE `id` = ?';
        $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $query->bind_param(
            $file->id
        );
        $query->execute();
    }
    return $file;
```

First insert without position, then update the position based on the last inserted id.